# iOS Swift 5 API Response isn't JSON, it has semicolons?

Tags: ios, swift, api, response

I am trying to work with an api response which comes back nicely in postman but when I print it in swift, it has semicolons at the end of lines

I have tried options and various ways of altering the request and handling of the response to no avail. Why are the semicolons there?

******* Code snippet ******

```
let todosEndpoint: String = "https://url:3000/api/v1/somestring? 
query=$filter%3DUPC%20eq%20'somenumber'"
    guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

todosUrlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: 
"Content-Type")

todosUrlRequest.setValue("Bearer "+token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
guard let dataResponse = data,
    error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
    return }

    do{
        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary

        print(myJson!)
```

******** Results *****

```
Desired Results:
{
"@odata.context": "https://api.url.com/v1/$metadata#Products",
"value": [
    {
        "ASIN": null,
        "Height": null,
        "Length": null,
        "Width": null,
        "Weight": null,
        "Cost": null,
        "Margin": null,
        "RetailPrice": null,
        "StartingPrice": null,
        "ReservePrice": null,
         }
    ]
}


Actual Results:
{
"@odata.context" = "https://api.url.com/v1/$metadata#Products";
value =     (
            {
        ASIN = "<null>";
        BlockComment = "<null>";
        BlockedDateUtc = "<null>";
        Brand = BAZZILL;
        BundleType = None;
        BuyItNowPrice = "0.99";
        CategoryCode = "<null>";
        CategoryPath = "<null>";
        Classification = "<null>";
        Condition = "<null>";
        Cost = "<null>";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: That's how a "Dictionary" looks.. -_-..

Comment: So, in swiftonian, how does one extract the value 'Cost' for example please?

Comment: ahhhhh.... so one must not think json but must think dictionary! thanks Brandon. I think i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serializing the JSON as a dictionary which you are because you're doing:

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary
print(myJson!)
```

That means you access each field like:  `let comment = myJson["BlockComment"]`

However, it might be better to serialize as a structure:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    let asin: String?
    let blockComment: String?
    let brand: String?
    let buyItNowPrice: Float?
    let cost: Float?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case asin = "ASIN"
        case blockComment = "BlockComment"
        case brand = "Brand"
        case buyItNowPrice = "BuyItNowPrice"
        case cost = "Cost"
    }
}
```

then you'd do:

```
let product = try JSONDecoder().decode(Product.self)
print(product.cost)
print(product.brand)
//etc..
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types